# Connect eikon/refinitiv from RStudio

Tags: api, refinitiv-eikon-api, refinitiv-eikon

I have not found a solution posted how to download data from eikon/Refinitiv (I have my login/password) from my RStudio session that runs on a Unix server?

"eikonapir" seems to not work since it seems to required to run on an Windows OS.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned since posting this question is that:

1. RStudio running on a Unix system does not allow to connect to Refinitiv.
2. However, running locally (on my Windows Desktop) the Refinitiv application in the background using an advanced license and using a locally installed RStudio along with library(DatastreamDSWS2R) allows to connect to Refintiv's Datastream service.

While there could, of course, be an alternative solution and certainly a more technical explanation, I hope this does help.